# bash condition with regular expression

Tags: linux, bash

I'm going to learn bash programming. I just wrote a simple script in order to read numbers from input stream and check them to be in valid numerical format using regular expression.
in fact script should take input until the input be nonnumerical.
but it doesn't work properly.

code:

```
i=0
echo "plz enter number in valid format: " 

while true
do
        read input

        if  [[ $input =~ *[^0-9]* ]]; then
                echo "YOU DIDN'T ENTER A VALID NUMBER"
                break
        else
                arr[$i]=$input
                echo $input >> inputnums

        fi
done
```

when i enter a number or character condition is true. I mean i have echo "message" in output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing shell globing with regex, change your if condition to:

```
if  [[ $input =~ [^0-9] ]]; then
```

regex should use `.*` not `*` as used by shell shell glob.

Comment: @Kent: Thanks, I guess I wasn't that fast either as this question remained unanswered for 5 mins.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you. it works but i couldn't get it. I know that * represent zero or more characters but why i shouldn't use it in this situation? I mean what is difference of regex and shell glob?
can you explain more?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer that in regex you need to use `.*` for 0 or more characters

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `*` from the regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
echo "plz enter number in valid format: " 

while true
do
    read input

    if  [[ $input =~ ^[^0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "YOU DIDN'T ENTER A VALID NUMBER"
        break
    else
        arr[$i]=$input
        echo $input 
    fi
done
```